# SyntaxError: name 'v' is used prior to nonlocal declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, python-nonlocal

I looked at similar problems, but I could not find solutions for my mistake in them.

Problem:

In the `StartPage` block, I enter the data for the graph, which is based on these values ​​in the `PageOne` block, but the data of the first block cannot be used in the second block. They need to ask something either `global` or `nonlocal`, but I don’t know where to insert it.

```
import matplotlib
from math import *
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

g = 9.81

class Fly(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Fly")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Начальная страница")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        v = IntVar()
        angle = IntVar()
        x0 = IntVar()
        y0 = IntVar()
        v2 = IntVar()
        angle2 = IntVar()
        x02 = IntVar()
        y02 = IntVar()
        v3 = IntVar()
        angle3 = IntVar()
        x03 = IntVar()
        y03 = IntVar()

        frame2 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame2.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для первого графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x0)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y0)
        entry.pack()

        frame3 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame3.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для второго графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v2)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle2)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x02)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y02)
        entry.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для третьего графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v3)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle3)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x03)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y03)
        entry.pack()

        nonlocal v
        nonlocal angle
        nonlocal x0
        nonlocal y0
        nonlocal v2
        nonlocal angle2
        nonlocal x02
        nonlocal y02
        nonlocal v3
        nonlocal angle3
        nonlocal x03
        nonlocal y03


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Generate")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Поменять значения",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        t = ((2 * v * sin(angle)) / g)
        vx = v * cos(angle)

        t2 = ((2 * v2 * sin(angle2)) / g)
        vx2 = v2 * cos(angle2)

        t3 = ((2 * v3 * sin(angle3)) / g)
        vx3 = v3 * cos(angle3)

        dx = 0.01
        xmin = x0
        xmax = vx * t * cos(angle)
        xmin2 = x02
        xmax2 = vx2 * t2 * cos(angle2)
        xmin3 = x03
        xmax3 = vx3 * t3 * cos(angle3)

        def func(x0, v, g, y0, angle):
            y = x0 * tan(angle) - (1 / (2 * v ** 2)) * ((g * x0 ** 2) / (cos(angle) ** 2)) + y0
            if y == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y


        def func2(x02, v2, y02, angle2):
            y2 = x02 * tan(angle2) - (1 / (2 * v2 ** 2)) * ((g * x02 ** 2) / (cos(angle2) ** 2)) + y02
            if y2 == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y2


        def func3(x03, v3, y03, angle3):
            y3 = x03 * tan(angle3) - (1 / (2 * v3 ** 2)) * ((g * x03 ** 2) / (cos(angle3) ** 2)) + y03
            if y3 == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y3


        xlist = mlab.frange(xmin, xmax, dx)
        xlist2 = mlab.frange(xmin2, xmax2, dx)
        xlist3 = mlab.frange(xmin3, xmax3, dx)

        ylist = [func(x0, v, g, y0, angle) for x0 in xlist]
        ylist2 = [func2(x02, v2, y02, angle2) for x02 in xlist2]
        ylist3 = [func3(x03, v3, y03, angle3) for x03 in xlist3]

        pylab.plot(xlist, ylist)
        pylab.plot(xlist2, ylist2)
        pylab.plot(xlist3, ylist3)

        pylab.show()


app = Fly()
app.mainloop()
```

I don’t know what part of the code to throw, so I threw off the whole.

I apologize to those who read this, but did not understand my problem. Please write what will be incomprehensible, I will try to give more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare such variables in the scope of the module, i.e. at the top of your code put:

```
import matplotlib
from math import *
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

g = 9.81
v = IntVar()
angle = IntVar()
x0 = IntVar()
y0 = IntVar()
v2 = IntVar()
angle2 = IntVar()
x02 = IntVar()
y02 = IntVar()
v3 = IntVar()
angle3 = IntVar()
x03 = IntVar()
y03 = IntVar()
```

then rewrite `StartPage` like this:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Начальная страница")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        frame2 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame2.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для первого графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x0)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y0)
        entry.pack()

        frame3 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame3.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для второго графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v2)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle2)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x02)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y02)
        entry.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для третьего графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v3)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle3)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x03)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y03)
        entry.pack()
```

As another (maybe nicer?) alternative, you might consider using a shared object to store the data, and give both frames a reference to that object, for example:

```
import matplotlib
from math import *
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

g = 9.81


class MyData():
    v = IntVar()
    angle = IntVar()
    x0 = IntVar()
    y0 = IntVar()
    v2 = IntVar()
    angle2 = IntVar()
    x02 = IntVar()
    y02 = IntVar()
    v3 = IntVar()
    angle3 = IntVar()
    x03 = IntVar()
    y03 = IntVar()


class Fly(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Fly")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        data = MyData

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self, data)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, data):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Начальная страница")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        frame2 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame2.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для первого графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.v)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.angle)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.x0)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.y0)
        entry.pack()

        frame3 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame3.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для второго графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.v2)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.angle2)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.x02)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.y02)
        entry.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для третьего графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.v3)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.angle3)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.x03)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=data.y03)
        entry.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, data):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Generate")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Поменять значения",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        t = ((2 * v * sin(data.angle)) / g)
        vx = data.v * cos(data.angle)

        t2 = ((2 * data.v2 * sin(data.angle2)) / g)
        vx2 = data.v2 * cos(data.angle2)

        t3 = ((2 * data.v3 * sin(data.angle3)) / g)
        vx3 = data.v3 * cos(data.angle3)

        dx = 0.01
        xmin = data.x0
        xmax = vx * t * cos(data.angle)
        xmin2 = data.x02
        xmax2 = vx2 * t2 * cos(data.angle2)
        xmin3 = data.x03
        xmax3 = vx3 * t3 * cos(data.angle3)

        def func(x0, v, g, y0, angle):
            y = x0 * tan(angle) - (1 / (2 * v ** 2)) * ((g * x0 ** 2) / (cos(angle) ** 2)) + y0
            if y == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y


        def func2(x02, v2, y02, angle2):
            y2 = x02 * tan(angle2) - (1 / (2 * v2 ** 2)) * ((g * x02 ** 2) / (cos(angle2) ** 2)) + y02
            if y2 == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y2


        def func3(x03, v3, y03, angle3):
            y3 = x03 * tan(angle3) - (1 / (2 * v3 ** 2)) * ((g * x03 ** 2) / (cos(angle3) ** 2)) + y03
            if y3 == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y3


        xlist = mlab.frange(xmin, xmax, dx)
        xlist2 = mlab.frange(xmin2, xmax2, dx)
        xlist3 = mlab.frange(xmin3, xmax3, dx)

        ylist = [func(x0, data.v, g, data.y0, data.angle) for x0 in xlist]
        ylist2 = [func2(x02, data.v2, data.y02, data.angle2) for x02 in xlist2]
        ylist3 = [func3(x03, data.v3, data.y03, data.angle3) for x03 in xlist3]

        pylab.plot(xlist, ylist)
        pylab.plot(xlist2, ylist2)
        pylab.plot(xlist3, ylist3)

        pylab.show()


app = Fly()
app.mainloop()
```

There are other errors too, but this works around your scoping issue.

Comment: Does this mean that I will have to find other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: @Mxxn I think we have solved the problem that was the original question. If you still have problems with something else (say, the `IntVar`s) then you could post another question about that.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, it's your nonlocal declarations. I've switched them to globals and called them in the appropriate order. Your code will still not run as you have some type issues later on, but that is out of the scope of the question

```
import matplotlib
from math import *
import pylab
from matplotlib import mlab
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

g = 9.81


class Fly(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Fly")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Начальная страница")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()

        global v
        v = IntVar()

        global angle
        angle = IntVar()

        global x0
        x0 = IntVar()

        global y0
        y0 = IntVar()

        global v2
        v2 = IntVar()

        global angle2
        angle2 = IntVar()

        global x02
        x02 = IntVar()

        global y02
        y02 = IntVar()

        global v3
        v3 = IntVar()

        global angle3
        angle3 = IntVar()

        global x03
        x03 = IntVar()

        global y03
        y03 = IntVar()















        frame2 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame2.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для первого графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x0)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y0)
        entry.pack()

        frame3 = Frame(self, borderwidth=4, relief=GROOVE)
        frame3.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для второго графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v2)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle2)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x02)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y02)
        entry.pack()

        first = Label(self, text='Данные для третьего графика')
        first.pack()

        second = Label(self, text='Начальная скорость')
        second.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=v3)
        entry.pack()

        third = Label(self, text='Угол выстрела')
        third.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=angle3)
        entry.pack()

        fourth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата x')
        fourth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=x03)
        entry.pack()

        fifth = Label(self, text='Начальная координата y')
        fifth.pack()
        entry = Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=y03)
        entry.pack()






class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Generate")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Поменять значения",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        f = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        t = ((2 * v * sin(angle)) / g)
        vx = v * cos(angle)

        t2 = ((2 * v2 * sin(angle2)) / g)
        vx2 = v2 * cos(angle2)

        t3 = ((2 * v3 * sin(angle3)) / g)
        vx3 = v3 * cos(angle3)

        dx = 0.01
        xmin = x0
        xmax = vx * t * cos(angle)
        xmin2 = x02
        xmax2 = vx2 * t2 * cos(angle2)
        xmin3 = x03
        xmax3 = vx3 * t3 * cos(angle3)

        def func(x0, v, g, y0, angle):
            y = x0 * tan(angle) - (1 / (2 * v ** 2)) * ((g * x0 ** 2) / (cos(angle) ** 2)) + y0
            if y == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y


        def func2(x02, v2, y02, angle2):
            y2 = x02 * tan(angle2) - (1 / (2 * v2 ** 2)) * ((g * x02 ** 2) / (cos(angle2) ** 2)) + y02
            if y2 == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y2


        def func3(x03, v3, y03, angle3):
            y3 = x03 * tan(angle3) - (1 / (2 * v3 ** 2)) * ((g * x03 ** 2) / (cos(angle3) ** 2)) + y03
            if y3 == 0:
                return 0.0
            return y3


        xlist = mlab.frange(xmin, xmax, dx)
        xlist2 = mlab.frange(xmin2, xmax2, dx)
        xlist3 = mlab.frange(xmin3, xmax3, dx)

        ylist = [func(x0, v, g, y0, angle) for x0 in xlist]
        ylist2 = [func2(x02, v2, y02, angle2) for x02 in xlist2]
        ylist3 = [func3(x03, v3, y03, angle3) for x03 in xlist3]

        pylab.plot(xlist, ylist)
        pylab.plot(xlist2, ylist2)
        pylab.plot(xlist3, ylist3)

        pylab.show()



app = Fly()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error below:

> SyntaxError: name 'x' is used prior to nonlocal declaration

When trying to use **the local and non-local variables `x`** in inner() as shown below:

```py
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 5
    def inner():
        x = 10 # Local variable
        x += 1
        print(x)
        
        nonlocal x # Non-local variable
        x += 1
        print(x)
    inner()
outer()
```

And, when trying to use **the global and non-local variables `x`** in inner() as shown below:

```py
x = 0
def outer():
    x = 5
    def inner():
        global x # Global variable
        x += 1
        print(x)
        
        nonlocal x # Non-local variable
        x += 1
        print(x)
    inner()
outer()
```

So, I renamed `x` to `y` for the local variable as shown below:

```py
x = 0
def outer():
    y = 5 # Here
    def inner():
        x = 10
        x += 1
        print(x)
        
        nonlocal y # Here
        y += 1
        print(y)
    inner()
outer()
```

Then, the error was solved as shown below:

```
11
6
```

And, I renamed`x` to `y` for the non-local variable as shown below:

```py
x = 0
def outer():
    y = 5 # Here
    def inner():
        global x
        x += 1
        print(x)
        
        nonlocal y # Here
        y += 1 # Here
        print(y) # Here
    inner()
outer()
```

Then, the error was solved as shown below:

```
1
6
```